# Connecting all computers to a switch then to a server- can it be done?

Tags: home-networking, windows-server-2012

I want a setup similar to this:

[image: Network Diagram]

Do I need to buy another NIC or something for this configuration to work?  How is plugging all computers into a switch, then the switch into the server, and then having a ethernet cable on the other interface going to the router... different from just plugging the server into the switch with the computers and then plugging the switch into the router? How does this differ in functionality?

Comment: Note that in your design, the "server" is acting as a "router", and yes, it will need two nics. This design is no differant from any normal soho network, except the router is not a commercial device, but a computer (known as a Bastion Host) with two nics, locked down and stripped of any exploitable services on the public interface, a firewall, and running some services like DNS, DNS relay (for resolving external sites), DHCP, etc. Depending on the Os on the "server" you may or may not have NAT functionality, so I'd use something like PFSense so I could have NAT. https://www.pfsense.org/

Comment: i see. thanks. if i have a wireless router already, will i need to disable dhcp if i want to have it on my server? also, if i just plug the server into the switch as i said as opposed to the server going to the router, will that just act like a regular fileserver with no intermediary functionality like AD/dhcp/dns?

Comment: The server/router must be inline between your ISP equipment and your switch. The router defines your network and separates it from the ISP's network. if you didn't have a router in line to break the networks up, your computers would have to pull an IP address from the ISP, not from your DHCP server, in order to get an IP that could access the Internet. If your hosts got their IPs from the DHCP server, there would be no device that could translate between your IP addresses and the ISPs, and the ISP equipment could not communicate with your hosts. you need a router to do that if you want dhcp.

Comment: CONT. Routers must have multiple NICs with one network on each, and they route traffic between these interfaces. Thats why you can't just connect the server and the ISP modem to the switch directly. if the switch is on the Modem, then the switch is part of the ISPs network, not your own. the switch cannot treat some of the ports as in your network, and others in the ISP network.

Comment: Is this really a simple ISP modem or is it a router? Does your ISP require some sort of dial-in (like PPPoE on DSL)?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned. the server in your design is acting as a gateway(router). and it requires two nic to function (1 to modem, 1 to switch). you will have to configure network services such as DHCP, DNS, firewall, NAT...etc on the server OS.

As for the wireless router, you may have one of its LAN port connected to the switch, and disable all routing functions (NAT, DHCP...etc) then it will basically serve as a wireless AP, (the server still being the gateway/router

it is not recommended to run anything other than network services on the server. therefore i wont recommend running file server on the server. since that any interruption or failure to the server means total network outage.

Alternatively, you may use a ordinary SOHO router to serve as gateway, and connect router with switch. then all PC & the server goes to the switch. that way you are safe to use server as file server