# is it high risk to use one Switch for pc and server together

Tags: networking

Is it high risk to use one Switch for pc and server together? As we have budget shortage.

So we have only 1 switch that will use for all PC and Server.

Please help explain the pro and con.

Comment: What kind of switch? Network switch? KVM switch? other kind of switch?

Comment: You want to use one switch for PC and server together, rather than...? What are the other alternatives that don't fit in your budget?

Answer (score -2):

If you have more than 5 computers, or there are heavy internet users (online gaming or streaming video, for example), a switch will reduce the network load and significantly improve network response.

It also depends on how to you connect the client and server to the switch. Are the clients conntect to the switch first, then the switch connect to the server, or other configuration?

This link can be refered to for some suggestions:
[Connecting all computers to a switch then to a server- can it be done?](https://superuser.com/questions/850239/connecting-all-computers-to-a-switch-then-to-a-server-can-it-be-done)

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is completely wrong. Firstly, it's literally impossible to connect multiple clients to the Internet without a switch. If you have multiple clients competing for bandwidth, then you already have a switch. It may be integrated into the router, but still. Adding additional switch won't change a thing, because there's still just one network connection shared by all clients.

Comment: Secondly, all ports on a (non-managed) switch are made equal. You can't "connect clients to the switch first, then switch to the server" because they are simply all connected to each other using the switch. No port is privileged. The server is simply another participant in the network, just like clients. From networking perspective there's no difference.